# Print File from API Response

Tags: reactjs, pdf, axios

I want to open the print window directly from API response, my API response is File(PDF),
Any code or library to do this job? Thanks in advance

I'm using Axios to make API call from reactJS.

Below is my response header :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
x-powered-by: Express
access-control-allow-origin: *
content-type: application/download
content-disposition: attachment;filename=Data.pdf
content-transfer-encoding: binary
content-length: 10022
etag: W/"2726-xCLkM5JoMiumRWO1c0J4veCsUxQ"
date: Wed, 14 Jul 2021 09:33:13 GMT
connection: close
```

And First 10 lines from response preview :

```
%PDF-1.4
1 0 obj
<<
/Title (þÿ)
/Creator (þÿ)
/Producer (þÿQt 5.5.1)
/CreationDate (D:20210714093313)
>>
endobj
2 0 obj
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this particular library called [react pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pdf)

Then you can use the component as

```
<ReactPDF
   file={{
      data: renderPdf
}}/>
```

where renderPdf would be the variable you have saved your response to.